# Verificar que un dato fue actualizado

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy leyendo los registros de una base de datos en SQL y me gustaría saber si, ¿hay alguna manera de identificar si "Customer", "Name", "Status" y "Customer Since" han sido editados o actualizados?

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                // Console.WriteLine("Done.");

                string sql = "select Customer, Name, Status, Customer_Since from Customer;";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while(reader.Read()){
                            customers.Add(
                                new Customer {
                                    customer = reader["Customer"].ToString(),
                                    Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                                    Status = reader["Status"].ToString(),
                                    Customer_since = (DateTime)reader["Customer_Since"]
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Comment: podrias hacer la comprobacion de 2 maneras, creando un campo para guardar el usuario al momento de registrar y luego de un update para una actualizacion o podrias crear otro campo en tu base de datos que guarde el momento que el usuario fue actualizado , luego hacer la comparacion de los campos y mostrar alguna imagen que lo indique con alguna otra informacion

Answer (score 1):

Una tecnica para conocer si el registro fue actualizado es por medio de un `timestamp` o `rowversion`.

[Part 20 Using ROWVERSION or TIMESTAMP to detect concurrency conflicts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cbrnsr1Q1e4)

La idea es que en la tabla crees un campo adicional del tipo `rowversion` esto generara una marca que debera cambiar cuando impactas un cambio en el registro.

La idea es que al momento de realizar un UPDATE compares el valor de `rowversion` que tienes cuando realizaste el SELECT y lo compares con el actual de la tabla en la db:

- si coincide nadie modifico el registro
- si es diferente indicara que alguien lo modifico

No se detecta por ciertos campos en concretos lo que validas es si el registros sufrio una actualizacion previa a tu modificacion, a esto se lo llama `concurrencia optimista`

Comment: gracias , no conocia esta informacion leonardo (y)